How to identiy IPv6 address type, as Prefered or Temporary
Doing address discovery using NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() and iterating through the list to get the addresses (InetAddress) in each interface, how can I determine if an IPv6 address is the Preferred address or a Temporary address?
Thank you for any thoughts.
Looking at, and printing all the methods in InetAddress, Inet4Address and Inet6Address I can find no reference to a flag or indicator, indicating a Temporary or Preferred address for the host.

You might want to at least add the right tag for the language you are using.

Thanks, Good Point. Edited the question to include the language.

Do either of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833765/detect-temporary-ipv6-address-crossplatform  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442119/find-temporary-ipv6-address-using-getadaptersaddresses

@WJS No they don't, as none of the required APIs are present in Java.
